# Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Monitor Config Problem

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am using dual monitors with my laptop.  I used nvidia's configuration tool (nvidia-xconfig) to detect the second monitor (via HDMI) and setup twinview, no problems.  Now, if I try to boot up without that monitor, I'm having a strange issue.

On boot, everything is normal.  Then, I get an error on the left side of the screen saying checks failed for a large variety of screen resolutions and frequencies.  In addition, my mouse only moves in a small column on the left side of the screen, and clicks are registered, quite strangely, on the right side of the screen.  I can't click on Unity at all.  However, the keyboard works, so I can get into the terminal with the Windows key.  I tried getting into nvidia-xconfig, but the GUI did not come up.  I tried to manually edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but I don't know what to change.

Does anyone know of a way I can reset my display settings through the command line or through manually editing xorg.conf?  Thanks!

Comment: There's a tweak in xorg.conf for nvidia drivers that forces the detection of an absent monitor as if was plugged in. The exact tweak is described in readme file which is distributed along with the nvidia driver.

Comment: The developers for 12.04 are actively looking for testers with multiple monitors.  This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).